# Encoding issue using Try::Tiny module

Tags: perl, encoding

Hello mates I have the following sub that is supposed to get a error log when things go bad:

```
sub _log_warning {
    my $log = Log::Minimal::Instance->new(
        base_dir =>
          &config->current->{'log_reader'}->{'base_dir'},
        pattern => &config->current->{'log_reader'}->{'pattern'},
    );
    $log->infof("Could not register to DB. Got $_");
}
```

And I activate with Try::Tiny

```
use Try::Tiny;
try { _log_to_database(); }
catch {
     _log_warning();
 };
```

To check this handles errors well, I provoke an error, a missing file error. The Log I get is:

```
 2013-07-04T11:46:39 [INFO] Could not register to DB. Got ã<81><9d>ã<81>®ã<82><88>ã<81>    
 <86>ã<81>ªã<83><95>ã<82>¡ã<82>¤ã<83>«ã<82><84>ã<83><87>ã<82>£ã<83 ....
```

I can't read this. But when I try to output the error not as a log file, but in STDOUT, I get the message well:

```
 The try block died with: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません: /var/log/....
```

The message is in Japanese though.
How can I get the message in proper encoding (in Japanese) when the output is a log file and not stdout?
I'm on centos.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider here. But, firstly, where does Log::Server come from? I can't find it on CPAN. You probably need to either configure that (or, in the worse case, fix it) to be aware of Unicode.

Comment: "Log::Server" is a module that only has a "use parent.." line to load Log::Minimal::Instance (Cpan). It's main methods are "new" and "infof" for leaving logs. I see, so basically you would suspect that Log::Minimal::Instance is where the encoding issue arises?